# NodeJS Bootstrap dependencies location

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies, tether

I know that Bootstrap dependencies involve using Tether and jQuery before including Bootstrap JS library. I have installed Bootstrap via my *package.json* file :

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    [...]
  }
```

Which give me this output where we can see the dependencies :

```
bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 node_modules/bootstrap
├── tether@1.4.0
└── jquery@3.2.1
```

To include Bootstrap in my page I then use the following paths :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
---
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But where to find Tether and jQuery ? There is no folder in node_modules that was created.

Should I install them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It looks obvious now...

The dependencies are included inside the Bootstrap folder so :

```
node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/tether
node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/jquery
```